# How to include an image and to set items at right of it

Tags: beamer

How to set items at right of an image of a frame?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
    \item A.
    \item B.
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I'm just trying to include an image at left-center of the page and to include some items at its right.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `columns` environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{columns}
\column{.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\column{.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
    \item A.
    \item B.
\end{itemize}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjusting the settings as required in a comment: notice that I placed the itemize inside a `\parbox` so yo can easily shift it horizontally if required (the length used in the `\hspace` has also to be added to the `\parbox` width):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{columns}
\column{4.5cm}
\includegraphics[width=4.5cm,height=4.5cm]{example-image-b}
\column{\dimexpr\textwidth-4.5cm\relax}
\hspace*{-20pt}\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth+20pt\relax}{%
\begin{itemize}
    \item A.
    \item B.
\end{itemize}%
}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: can you please set the image to `width=4.5cm,height=4.5cm` and reduce the space between the image and the itemize. Because using your solution makes the space between them very large.

Comment: @dgs: of course, most of answers in the site are examples: you have to adapt the solution to your actual needs.

Comment: @dgs please see my updated answer.